# "loading shared libraries" error using VLFeat in C

Tags: c, vlfeat

I am trying to use VLFeat library in C, as given on the website
http://www.vlfeat.org/gcc.html.

I downloaded and installed the library. I use the `glnxa64` architecture. The library is located at `/A/B/C/vlfeat-0.9.18`

My code is as follows:

```
    extern "C" {
    #include <vl/generic.h>
    #include <vl/sift.h>
    }

    int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
    {
    VL_PRINT ("Hello world!") ;
    return 0;
    }
```

I compile my code using the following statement,

```
g++ main.cpp -o vlfeat-test -I/A/B/C/vlfeat-0.9.18 -L/A/B/C/vlfeat-0.9.18/bin/glnxa64/ -lvl
```

But when I run it, I get the following error

```
./vlfeat-test: error while loading shared libraries: libvl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my shared library not found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111293/why-is-my-shared-library-not-found)

Comment: But I am working on a server and do not have admin rights. The solution given in the above link does not work for me.

Comment: You don't need to be admin to change your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  You can also try various linker flags like the ones described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484265/how-do-i-get-rid-of-ld-library-path-at-run-time

Answer (score 2):

When your program is loaded, linux loads the necessary libraries.

You need to create a symbolic link in /usr/lib/ to your libvl.so file

```
sudo ln -s /home/[YourPATH]/vlfeat-0.9.20/bin/[YourArchitecture]/libvl.so /usr/lib/libvl.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Before running your test, in the same console:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/A/B/C/vlfeat-0.9.18/bin/glnxa64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then

```
./vlfeat-test
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when your program load. Linux doesn't know where your vl library is.

copy libvl.so to /usr/lib

```
sudo cp [VLFEAT_PATH]/bin/[YOUR_ARCHITECTURE]/libvl.so /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

[This worked for same problem when using the .mex files through MATLAB in Ubuntu].

You may need to update the links and cache to the recent shared libraries by running

```
sudo ldconfig
```

You can permanently add the library path `/A/B/C/vlfeat-0.9.18/bin/glnxa64` or a custom directory with your (links to) shared libraries, e.g., `/home/username/lib` in the `ldconfig` files:

```
sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf
```

to add the line(s)

```
/A/B/C/vlfeat-0.9.18/bin/glnxa64
```

Verify by running

```
ldconfig -v | grep libvl.so
```